# jquery - change background position on textbox input change

Tags: jquery, html, css

Let's say I have a spritesheet with a size of 600x150px. Both of the image-wrapper classes have a width of 150px containing the sprites. Now, what I want to do is I want to move the background position of the .image-wrapper by -150px when there is a value in the textbox. If not, it will return back to its original position.

I won't have any problems if I'll just toggle the background color like changing it from red to blue, but I don't know what to do since it's the background position I have to control. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

HTML

```
 <div class="column">
        <div class="image-wrapper one">

        </div>
        <h5>TITLE</h5>
        <input type="text" class="tagged-input">
    </div>

    <div class="column">
        <div class="image-wrapper two">

        </div>
        <h5>TITLE</h5>
        <input type="text" class="tagged-input">
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.image-wrapper {
            width:160px;
            height:150px;
            background:url('spritesheet.png');
    }

            .one {
                    background-position: 0px;
             }

    .two {
        background-position: -300px;
    }
```

JS

```
$('.tagged-input').on('change',function(){
        if($(this).val() != "") {

        } else {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Updated jQuery and [Working Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/ezqr7/5/)

this **jQuery** might help:

```
    $('.tagged-input').change(function(){
     var currPos = $(this).parent("div").find(".image-wrapper").css('backgroundPosition').split(" ");
     var posX = Number(currPos[0].split("px")[0]);
        if($(this).val() != "") {
            var newPos = posX - 150 + "px";
            alert(newPos); /* just to check if I'm getting the right values */
            $(this).parent("div").find(".image-wrapper").css({"background-position": newPos});
            } 
        else {
            var newPos = posX + 150 + "px";
            alert(newPos); /* just to check if I'm getting the right values */
            $(this).parent("div").find(".image-wrapper").css({"background-position": newPos});
            }
   });
```

This gets the current value of the background-position css property of the `.image-wrapper` that is a sibling of the concerned `.tagged-input` and changes the property value depending on the value of the `.tagged-input`.

**[SAMPLE in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ezqr7/5/)**

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but I don't think that's the approach I am looking for. What if I added a value to the .tagged-input in the .one class? The best approach that I can think of is to get the background position value, like $(this).parent().find('.image-wrapper').getBackgroundPosition(?) and then subtract it to -150 pixels.

Comment: I've updated my answer, please check if thats the one you are looking for

Comment: Ooooh, so that's how you get the background position. Yes, this definitely is it! Thank you very much for the help. Cheers!